# Deploy files from one Org to Another

Tags: rest-api, deployment, metadata-api, files, file-storage

I have an object that has a 'Files' list in the 'Related' tab and have attached a Microsoft Word document to that list in my testing org. Is it possible to deploy that file so I don't have to manually add it in the next Org? Or would it be possible to store that file online and use an Apex script that retrieves that file and attaches it to the record in the 'Files' list?

Answer (score 1):

Files are essentially data records and thus cannot be deployed using change sets or the ant deployment tool.  You will need to use data export / import methods to copy your files from one org to another.

Comment: Thanks David, do you think it would be possible to do that in Apex? For example, store the file on Dropbox then write an Apex script that retrieves that file and sets it and adds it to the 'Files' list?

Comment: It might be possible but it would be very complicated.